# Using BeautifulSoup to parse multiple paragraphs in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to use BeautifulSoup in Python to parse html from such html

```
<p><b>Background</b><br />x0</p><p>x1</p>
<p><b>Innovation</b><br />x2</p><p>x3</p><p>x4</p>
<p><b>Activities</b><br />x5</p><p>x6</p>"
```

to this result:

```
Background: x0, x1
Innovation: x2, x3, x4
Activities: x5, x6
```

I have tired to use the python scripts below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
htmltext = "<p><b>Background</b><br />x0</p><p>x1</p>
         <p><b>Innovation</b><br />x2</p><p>x3</p><p>x4</p>
         <p><b>Activities</b><br />x5</p><p>x6</p>"
html = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
for n in html.find_all('b'):
    title_name = n.next_element
    title_content = n.nextSibling.nextSibling
    print title_name, title_content
```

However, I can only get this:

```
Background: x0
Innovation: x2
Activities: x5
```

Your comments are welcome and your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the sample html assigned to `htmls` be a docstring?

Comment: What exactly are the conditions for being included in the result? Do you want the innertext of every `<p>` element in between successive `<b>` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty new to beautifulsoup, but this is working for me:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmls = """<p><b>Background</b><br />x0</p><p>x1</p>
           <p><b>Innovation</b><br />x2</p><p>x3</p><p>x4</p>
           <p><b>Activities</b><br />x5</p><p>x6</p>"""
html = BeautifulSoup(htmls)

for n in html.find_all('b'):
    title_name = n.next_element
    title_content = n.nextSibling.nextSibling

    results = [title_content]
    for f in n.parent.find_next_siblings():
        el = f.next_element
        if isinstance(el, bs4.element.Tag) and el.name == 'b':
            break
        results.append(el)

    print title_name, results
```

Results:

```
Background [u'x0', u'x1']
Innovation [u'x2', u'x3', u'x4']
Activities [u'x5', u'x6']
```

I chose to use `isinstance(el, bs4.element.Tag) and el.name == 'b'` as the delimiter because in your example the `<p>` tags you are trying to capture have no children. This part should probably be a little different depending on the real webpage you are parsing.

Comment: As a side note -- it's best to avoid `isinstance` whenever possible when working in Python, because one of the benefits of object oriented programming is exactly that these kinds of checks are unnecessary. See, for a full explanation, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python).

Answer (score 2):

In `<p><b>Innovation</b><br />x2</p><p>x3</p><p>x4</p>` you are going to the `<b>` element and locating `x2` thought `next_element`.  That's all good.  But to locate `x3` and `x4` you need first to go up in the element hierarchy to the enclosing `<p>` element and from there locate the following `<p>`s enclosing `x3` and `x4`.

Comment: Ideally, it should be so. However, it seems that practically, when people code with html to write subtitles and the respective paragraphs, there is no specified element hierarchy for the enclosing <p>.

Answer (score 0):

You're stopping after reading one more tag, you need to keep going until you hit the next `<b>`. `nextSibiling` isn't going to work because the `<p>`'s you're parsing aren't siblings of the `<b>`'s. Try something like this:

```
def in_same_section(n):
    try:
        return n.next_element.name != u'b'
    except AttributeError:
        return True


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
htmltext ='''<p><b>Background</b><br />x0</p><p>x1</p>
         <p><b>Innovation</b><br />x2</p><p>x3</p><p>x4</p>
         <p><b>Activities</b><br />x5</p><p>x6</p>'''
html = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
for n in html.find_all('b'):
    title_name = n.string
    title_content = []
    while in_same_section(n):
        n = n.next_element
        try:
            if n.name == u'p':
                title_content += n.string
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

EDIT: Fixed the AttributeError, I think? I'm at work and can't test this code.

Comment: Fails at `while n.next_element.name != u'b':` with `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'name'` for me.